# Access API with Azure AD On Behalf of Token

Tags: rest-api, single-sign-on, azure-active-directory

I have my Salesforce organization configured to use SSO through Azure Active Directory.  Now I'm trying to use Azure AD and the 'On Behalf of Flow' to authenticate to the Salesforce REST API.

[image: On Behalf of Flow]

The Salesforce REST API would be Web API B in this diagram.

For the Setup of API A in the diagram I have added the `user_impersonation` permission for Salesforce and have granted Admin Consent for it.

[image: API A Permissions]

I'm able to successfully authenticate to API A and complete the token exchange, and receive a token for salesforce.  However when calling salesforce using the token I get back from Azure AD, I receive a 401 unauthorized.

This is the code I'm using on Web API A to exchange for the Salesforce Access Token

```
//Get the original JWT From the header
var authZhdr = Request.Headers.FirstOrDefault(h => h.Key.Equals("Authorization"));
var token = authZhdr.Value.FirstOrDefault().Substring(7);

//Exchange original JWT for Salesforce Token
IConfidentialClientApplication clnt = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
    .Create(_config.GetValue<string>("AzureAd:ClientId"))
    .WithClientSecret(_config.GetValue<string>("AzureAd:ClientSecret"))
    .WithAuthority(AadAuthorityAudience.AzureAdMyOrg)
    .WithTenantId(_config.GetValue<string>("AzureAd:TenantId"))
    .Build();
UserAssertion ua = new UserAssertion(token);

var res = clnt.AcquireTokenOnBehalfOf(new string[] { "https://<my-org>-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/user_impersonation" }, ua).ExecuteAsync().Result;

var access_token = res.AccessToken

var http = new HttpClient();
http.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://<my-org>-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v50.0/");
http.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthorizationRequestHeader("Bearer", access_token);

var resp = await http.GetAsync("/sobjects/Account");

Console.Log(resp.StatusCode)  //401 Unauthorized
```

I've checked the User Profile in Salesforce and it has API Access enabled. Is there anything additional within Salesforce that needs to be configured to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

I'm happy to provide further diagrams of the APIs and configurations within azure if needed, but everything seems to be working up until the Salesforce API call.

Comment: No such thing as `/user_impersonation` in Salesforce out of the box. For a confidential client, the on-behalf-of flow in Salesforce can be implemented via [JWT Bearer](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_jwt_flow.htm&type=5) flow. jwt.io lists .NET implementations or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61869035/how-to-generate-jwt-bearer-flow-oauth-access-tokens-from-a-net-core-client has a working example

Comment: the `/user_impersonation` is just the name of the scope within Azure AD that I am requesting.  It came out of the box when I added Salesforce as an API to the App Registration.

Comment: It's not an out of the box scope in Salesforce universe. Your app on Azure AD is allegedly translating this scope to something that Salesforce understands.

Comment: I ended up using the JWT Bearer flow to access salesforce.  

I think I was making some assumptions about what Azure AD was doing when exchanging tokens.  Thinking that maybe Azure AD could handle doing the [SAML Assertion Flow]( https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_web_sso_flow.htm&type=5) and just give me an access token to salesforce. 

Maybe that is possible in some fashion, but it wasn't readily apparent in any of the tutorials or documentation i looked at.